# Join same properties value from Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object, I want to know the best way of concatenating values from similar properties e.g.

```
arr:[
      {obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"joe"}}, 
      {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"developer"}}, 
      {obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"kevin"}}, 
      {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"architect"}}
]
```

I need to concatenate properties value of same obj_type property. 
expected result should be:

```
arr:[
      {obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"joe|kevin"}}, 
      {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"developer|architect"}}
]
```

i.e. values are concatenated based on obj_type.

Comment: Are you tried something?

Comment: This is simply a group by followed by a projection (select). Something like [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) will make this a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think code like this might be helpful for you:

```
//Objects to work with:
var arr = [{obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"joe"}},
          {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"developer"}},
          {obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"kevin"}},
          {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"architect"}}];
//Map from obj_type to {obj: …} objects:
var map = {};
//Iterating arr:
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var o = arr[i], type = o.obj.obj_type;
  if(type in map){
    map[type].obj.obj_foo += '|' + o.obj.obj_foo;
  }else{
    map[type] = o;
  }
}
//Putting map values to arr:
arr = [];
for(var key in map){
  arr.push(map[key]);
}
//Done:
console.log(arr);
```

Produced output looks like this:

> [ { obj: { obj_type: 1, obj_foo: 'joe|kevin' } },
>     { obj: { obj_type: 2, obj_foo: 'developer|architect' } } ]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

This variant doesn't change content of initial array.

```
var types = {};
var newArr = [];
var type, newObj;

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i ) {
    type = arr [ i ].obj.obj_type;
    if ( type in types ) {
        types[ type ].obj.obj_foo += '|' + arr[ i ].obj.obj_foo;
    } else {
        newObj = {
            obj: {
                obj_type: arr[ i ].obj.obj_type,
                obj_foo: arr[ i ].obj.obj_foo
            }
        };
        types[ type ] = newObj;
        newArr.push( newObj );
    }
}

return newArr; // result array
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the simplest approach:

```
// Your array
var arr = [
  {obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"joe"}}, 
  {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"developer"}}, 
  {obj:{obj_type:1, obj_foo:"kevin"}}, 
  {obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"architect"}}
];

// Loop over all elements
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var a = arr[i].obj;
  // Compare to each other element
  for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    var b = arr[j].obj;
    // If the obj_type is equal...
    if(a.obj_type === b.obj_type) {
      // Merge data...
      a.obj_foo += '|' + b.obj_foo;
      // Remove other element
      arr.splice(j--, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Output (from node.js):

```
[ { obj: { obj_type: 1, obj_foo: 'joe|kevin' } },
  { obj: { obj_type: 2, obj_foo: 'developer|architect' } } ]
```

Comment: I believe you have a bug in your code, because your i,j indices may become larger than arr.length when splicing. This means that appending ```{obj:{obj_type:2, obj_foo:"cthulhu"}}``` to arr produces ```[ { obj: { obj_type: 1, obj_foo: 'joe|kevin' } },
  { obj: { obj_type: 2, obj_foo: 'developer|architect' } },
  { obj: { obj_type: 2, obj_foo: 'cthulhu' } } ]```

Comment: @JakobRunge No, JavaScript does not cache the result of `arr.length` between loop-iterations. `arr.length` will be reevaluated after each `arr.splice` invocation so neither `i` nor `j` will ever exceed `arr.length`.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I've put that into node.js and see that the indices change as expected. So my guess for the error was wrong but the error still appears.

Comment: @JakobRunge Oh, thanks for the hint, I missed the `--` in `arr.splice(j--, 1);`